# Recoding Values For a Single Column in R (includes NULL values)

Tags: r, null, rstudio

I have a dataframe named data.comp and within it a column named RELAFFIL. The values within the column range from 22 to 107, but there are also numerous NULL values. I wanted to recode the values to 0 for all NULL values, and 1 for all other cases. I have tried multiple approaches and none have worked, FYI I list the ones I've tried below. Also FYI I have the following packages loaded: dplyr, readr, and car.

```
data.comp$RELAFFIL <- with(data.comp, ifelse(is.null(data.comp$RELAFFIL), 0, 1))

data.comp$RELAFFIL[is.null(data.comp$RELAFFIL)] <- 0

data.comp$RELAFFIL[is.finite(data.comp$RELAFFIL)] <- 1

car::recode(data.comp$RELAFFIL, "NULL = 0; else = 1")

data.comp$RELAFFIL <- data.comp$RELAFFIL %>% base::ifelse(is.null(data.comp$RELAFFIL), 0, 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Does `data.comp$RELAFFIL <- ifelse(is.null(data.comp$RELAFFIL), 0, 1)` not work?

Comment: No, it recodes all values (including NULL) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution for this is to improt file mentioning NA strings as null. code is provided below

```
data.comp <- read.csv("your csv file",stringsAsFactors = F,na.strings = c("null"))
data.comp[is.na(data.comp)] <- 0

data.comp$RELAFFI_new <-ifelse(data.comp$RELAFFIL == 0,0,1)
```

this will give your required output